# Is ggplot2's continuous color scale incompatible with knitr's tikzDevice?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, knitr, tikz

I've been using knitr with R base graphics and tikz output for a while now, and wanted to try out `ggplot2` instead. However, this minimal example fails to produce any output with knitr 1.0.5:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<dev = 'tikz'>>=
library(ggplot2)
d = data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5, 6), c = c(7, 8, 9))
ggplot(d, aes(a, b, color = c)) + geom_point()
@
\end{document}
```

Instead, it fails with the message `Error in UseMethod("depth"): no applicable method for 'depth' applied to an object of class "NULL"`. Executing the code in R or choosing the png device will result in the expected graph. Omitting the color aesthetics or factoring `c` work with tikzDevice as well, so the continuous color scale seems to be the problem.

Is there anything I am doing wrong, or is that a bug?

Comment: sounds like a bug of `tikzDevice`; given that it is not actively maintained now, I suggest you use other devices for this specific case.

Comment: what a pity, since I really like having my axis labels typeset by TeX. Maybe I'll have a look at tikzDevice when I get around to it.

Comment: @Yihui I just stumbled on the same bug. Any recommendations on what device to use?

Comment: @RoyalTS you can use the default `pdf` device

Comment: @Yihui: Opened an issue with `tikzDevice` (with a MWE): https://github.com/yihui/tikzDevice/issues/132.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can get `tikzDevice` to work with your code by adding `dev.off()` to the end of the code block. For example:

```
cat("
    \\documentclass{article}
    \\begin{document}
    <<dev = 'tikz'>>=
    library(ggplot2)
    d = data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5, 6), c = c(7, 8, 9))
    ggplot(d, aes(a, b, color = c)) + geom_point()
    dev.off()
    @
    \\end{document}
", "test_works.Rtex")
knit("test_works.Rtex")
```

works fine.

I have also noticed that if calling `knit()` through an active R session on the (original) code, I am left with an active tikz device ...

```
cat("
    \\documentclass{article}
    \\begin{document}
    <<dev = 'tikz'>>=
    library(ggplot2)
    d = data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5, 6), c = c(7, 8, 9))
    ggplot(d, aes(a, b, color = c)) + geom_point()
    @
    \\end{document}
    ", file = "test_fails.Rtex")
knit("test_fails.Rtex")
dev.list()
```

Comment: thanks, you just saved me! how in the world did you figure that out? any idea why/what happens?

Answer (score 2):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/yihui/tikzDevice/issues/132), now resolved in the development version 0.10 of `tikzDevice`, which will hit CRAN soon. Until then, install using

```
devtools::install_github("yihui/tikzDevice")
```